# sba 1.6.7 - python on Windows

Tags: python, windows, computer-vision, cross-compiling

I am trying to install the sba's python wrapper (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sba) on windows 10. Is there a simple, easy way to do this? This is my last resort, I just wish to know if someone has been able to figure it out. I know it is able to be done in linux and looking through the source files of the library it seems as if it can be done in windows, but no concrete documentation is presented.

Some of the instructions provided by the library's website and source text files say one has to download the original sba library, which is written in c, and compile it as a shared library, a dll library in windows. I have been trying to achieve this using cmake and visual studio 2015 without success.

If somebody has done this or has some insight in the problem I will be very grateful for it to provide the solution.

Thanks!